# What interpolation does Tkinter use for curves?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interpolation

I came across this post:

[image] (https://pythongraphicgames.wordpress.com/tag/curved-line/) and I wondered what interpolation algorithm Tkinter used to create the curve. Cubic? Hermite? Cosine? and is there a way I can specify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses a bezier algorithm.

The line and polygon objects have a `smooth` option for controlling the smoothing. This is what the [canonical documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M136) says about that option:

> *-smooth* **smoothMethod**  :
> smoothMethod must have one of the forms accepted by Tcl_GetBoolean or a line smoothing method. Only **true** and **raw** are supported in the core (with **bezier** being an alias for **true**), but more can be added at runtime. If a boolean false value or empty string is given, no smoothing is applied. A boolean truth value assumes true smoothing. If the smoothing method is true, this indicates that the line should be drawn as a curve, rendered as a set of quadratic splines: one spline is drawn for the first and second line segments, one for the second and third, and so on. Straight-line segments can be generated within a curve by duplicating the end-points of the desired line segment. If the smoothing method is **raw**, this indicates that the line should also be drawn as a curve but where the list of coordinates is such that the first coordinate pair (and every third coordinate pair thereafter) is a knot point on a cubic Bezier curve, and the other coordinates are control points on the cubic Bezier curve. Straight line segments can be generated within a curve by making control points equal to their neighbouring knot points. If the last point is a control point and not a knot point, the point is repeated (one or two times) so that it also becomes a knot point.

Comment: Hmm, so there's no way to change the smoothing? If not, I suppose I could calculate the interpolation points myself and draw a smoothed line between them.